# Unable to understand Rust's error handling

Tags: rust, error-handling, rust-rocket

I have a Rocket.rs server and in one of its routes, I'm calling a function that finds documents of a collection and loops over it.

Find documents of a collection:

```
let participations: Cursor<Document> = collection.aggregate(pipeline, None).await.expect("Failed to fetch documents.");
```

Now after fetching the documents, it returns a Cursor and then I call `advance()` on it to loop over the cursor. The problem arises while using `is_ok()` instead of `expect()` on `advance()` result value.

When doing this my code works fine without any errors.

```
while participations.advance().await.expect("Failed to advance.") {
    let participation_doc = participations.deserialize_current();
}
```

But when I switch to this.

```
while participations.advance().await.is_ok() {
    let participation_doc = participations.deserialize_current();
}
```

My code fails with an error.

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'
```

After debugging I found out that this error is encountered when calling `participations.deserialize_current();`. It throws an error because `advance()` call was not successful. But why my loop was executed in the first place if the `advance()` call was not successful *`is_ok()` should've returned `false`*. And why does my code work fine when using `expect()`. If there's an error then *`expect()` should make my code panic*.

What I want is my code to not panic even if `advance()` fails that's why I was using `is_ok()`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't document what the APIs you're using is (neither rocket nor tokio seem relevant, but the entire cursor/document/advance/deserialize_current bit very much is), nor do you provide any sort of runnable code, so it's difficult to put forth any hypothesis.

Comment: I think the issue is related to much more basic rust than rocket or tokio. I should remove those tags.

Comment: The thing that you try to use inside the `while` is different from the thing you check with `is_ok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, you didn't specify which library this `advance()` call comes from, but I'm assuming it is [`Cursor::advance`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/struct.Cursor.html#method.advance) from MongoDB.

The signature of that method is:

```rust
pub async fn advance(&mut self) -> mongodb::error::Result<bool>;
```

So, it is an asynchronous method which will either give you a Boolean, or a MongoDB error. As the docs say:

> The return value indicates whether new results were successfully returned (true) or if the cursor has been closed (false).

By awaiting, you get a value of `mongodb::error::Result<bool>`. Then, you do two different things with it in your code snippets:

- `result.expect("Failed to advance.")` (similar to `result.unwrap()`)

  Here, you are saying "assume there was no MongoDB error (or else panic), then check whether there are more values available".
- `result.is_ok()`

  Here, you are saying "check whether there was a MongoDB error".

Notice that in the second case, you are not actually using the Boolean value. (Did the compiler not warn you about this by any chance?) Maybe the API could be designed a bit better, but the first variant is slightly better. If you also want to gracefully handle errors, you want to check *both* that there is no MongoDB error, and that there are more values available from the `Cursor`.

Something like this:

```rust
loop {
    match participations.advance().await {
        Ok(true) => {
            let participation_doc = participations.deserialize_current();
            todo!(); // do things with participation_doc ...
        }
        Ok(false) => break, // done with the collection
        Err(err) => todo!(), // handle err somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: "Did the compiler not warn you about this by any chance?" I don't think it can, the `is_ok()` call will just discard it internally, since it's a generic method there is no unused anything (and even if there was, `is_ok` would be designed to suppress it since that's literally its purpose).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think now I understand the mistake I was making. I didn't want to use expect because I didn't want my code to panic even if there was an error. I wanted to handle error gracefully. Your approach seems much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

tldr: result usage here is for internal errors, the actual value i.e Result<Ok(),Error> is used to indicate the presence of a value.

The return type of advance returns a `Result<bool>` ,  the way they have designed this result is for it to error if the issue is internal with the connection to the db itself, they are using `true` ,`false` to indicate the absence of a value instead of handling the result you should handle the returned value.
in your first line it will return a true or false value which while can understand, in your second your are checking for the result itself whether its `Ok` or an `Err(err)`  , even when it returns `Ok(false)` your second code snippet will run fine which is wrong.